# How to hide a parameter in React.js

Tags: reactjs, hidden

As you know, using React.js to deploy a web application will allow the users to inspect the web code.

However, I want to hide an specific value on a React application.
For example:

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const hidden_value = "username_paul";
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(hidden_value);
```

I will publically send the key value as a header parameter in an API request; but I do not want to allow see the "hidden_value" variable.

I was thinking about .env varibales; but I would like to explore different options (imagine the server is deployed on a file system).

Comment: I think you can use state management system like Redux or Context

Comment: Is the code you're showing running in the user's browser? If so, the hidden_value can't be entirely hidden from the user. Fundamentally, if the user's browser can see the code, the user can see it too. No way around that. You could compute the `key` server-side or while compiling, but that requires more info about your toolchain.

Comment: yes, the code will be on the user's browser; but maybe there is some workaround about it; or maybe it can be hidden or decompused between different files to make more difficult to get the value.